# Why are my upvotes displaced?

Tags: support, bug

**I wanted to upvote [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/60672/17609) and so I did. However, half an hour later the upvote was registered to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/28216/17609). I upvoted the intended answer again. Then this appeared, suggesting I upvoted yet [another answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20391/17609).**
[image]

**This time I didn't do anything and after a while, coming back, I got this.**

[image]

**I've encountered this problem before. I'm using Safari 6.0.3 (on a Mac with OS X 10.8.3) and have AdBlock 2.5.61 installed.**

Comment: It might just have been a temporary quirk. After you first upvoted the answer, did you refresh the page, and if so, did the problem persist after a refresh?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I don't recall, but will record the next time. I think that it has to do with the fact that my vote actually changes the ordering, and that SE doesn't keep good track of this. Perhaps one could try to upvote the third of four answers with each 0 votes, and see what happens... (with ordering set to votes). Also note that my initial vote _was_ misdirected by SE and stayed that way.

Comment: Yeah, if you can figure out how to reproduce this, that would be best. In general, because SE is a webapp, there's always an implied rule that you should refresh the page if you see something weird, before reporting it as a bug.

Comment: That's a new one by me.